# C++ atomic memory order vs thread events such as notify()

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

An atomic bool "ready" is shared between two threads. Thread A is doing some task, and thread B is waiting to be notified by A. A will set "ready" to True when the task is complete.

B has a wait-predicate that tests "ready". On waking, if "ready" is still False, B will go back to waiting. (This prevents spurious wakes from causing trouble)

A finishes its task, sets "ready" to True, then notifies B.

Question: How can I guarantee B will read (load) "ready" as True and not the older False?

```
atomic<bool> ready = false;

Thread A
do_something();
ready = true;
B_cond_var.notify_one();

Thread B:
B_cond_var.wait( mtx, []() -> bool { return ready == true; } );
do_something(); // <- sometimes doesn't happen
```

I have found that sometimes B reads "ready" as False, and never wakes. Which means from its point of view the notify came *before* the update, even though in A the order is update, *then* notify.

NOTES: I have read entirely too much about memory ordering guarantees, and I think I understand enough about read and write ordering. However this question involves the ordering of memory updates and *thread communication events,* namely *notify*. I can't find a straight answer about how to guarantee ordering of these.

See eg:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/138018/memory-ordering-for-atomic-operations-in-c0x/

http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/

[Memory ordering behavior of std::atomic::load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783456/memory-ordering-behavior-of-stdatomicload?rq=1)

Also see C++11 standard section 29.3

UPDATE: Sorry for the confusion, the above is *pseudocode only*, boiled down from a much larger body and I have omitted things that don't enter into the problem such as the existence of a mutex on the condition variable. The working code exhibits the described reordering of variable update and notify roughly once every 400 days of runtime -- making it 3-4 per day in practice. This *is* actually happening.

Comment: I think all that's missing is the `return` in your lambda. Your compiler should be warning about this; it's making the lambda return an essentially random value each time.

Comment: @Cameron my mistake, the above is toy pseudocode boiling the problem down from a much larger body, not actual working code. The event I describe happens about every ~400 days runtime

Comment: The call to `B_cond_var.notify_one()` isn't ordered in relation to the accesses to `atomic<bool> ready` (my understanding is that `atomic<>` instances are ordered only in relation to themselves). I believe you'll need to hold the mutex while updating `ready`, which may eliminate any benefit from `ready` being atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need atomic variable if you are protecting it with condition variable. However, condition variables require mutexes, and I do not see mutexes in this code. Your lambda missess return statement as well.

Properly used condition variables will give you result you want.

Memory ordering is completely irrelevant here, since all Posix thread synchronization primitives impose full memory barriers.

Comment: Are you stating that the notify_one is equivalent to a memory update as regards total ordering? If so this is the first time I've read this stated unambiguously. And if it's true, I'd like to know how it is possible for B not to wake properly.

Comment: @bulletsweetp, mutexes are. And since condition variables always are used side-by-side with mutexes, they have the same property. On the actual question, you need to provide the exact code for me to tell you why it's not working. Right now your code is not compilable. As a matter of fact, cond vars impose total order themselves as well, as per Standard.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer -- what I was looking for was in your comment, the fact that "cond vars do impose total order" as well as atomic memory reads/writes. That was what I could not find in the Standard or anywhere else. Incidentally this fact indicates my theory about what was going wrong was incorrect and I've since found the real error.